# Can somebody give some inputs on how to debug to understand the behaviour of below golang snippet on macOS and linux?

Tags: linux, macos, go

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main started")
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
    fmt.Println("back to main")
}

func onReady() {
    icoFile := "sample.ico"
    icon, err := ioutil.ReadFile(icoFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err =", err)
    }

    systray.SetIcon(icon)
    systray.SetTitle("Awesome App")
    systray.SetTooltip("Pretty awesome超级棒")
    mQuit := systray.AddMenuItem("Quit", "Quit the whole app")

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-mQuit.ClickedCh:
                fmt.Println("Quit Systray")
                systray.Quit()
            }
        }

    }()
}

func onExit() {
    // clean up here
}
```

I lanuched the systray using above snippet in both mac and linux.

When quit is selected from the menu options, it behaves differently on both the platforms.
In linux(also in windows), after the systray is quit, control get backs to main and prints "back to main" whereas in macOS, this log is not occuring which means that the application exits from systray.Run function(control is not getting back to the main function).

Initially I thought that this could be the problem of getlantern/systray. When I dived deeper into the code, I found that the code is same for linux as well as macOS. Hence I am thinking that, the cause of this behaviour could be with OS.

I am looking for some pointer to analyse this issue. If there is any known source to understand this, it would be great help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in fact a difference in the library. The `Quit` method causes the internal `quit` function to be called. On Linux, `quit` hides the notifier and calls `gtk_main_quit` to end the GTK+ mainloop, which will cause `Run` to return. On Windows, `quit` sends a `WM_CLOSE` message to the app, which closes the systray "window" and eventually also causes the event loop to exit. On macOS, `quit` calls the [terminate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428417-terminate) method on the app, which does some cleanup and then exits the process. The Apple documentation even says:

> Don't bother to put final cleanup code in your app's `main()` function—it will never be executed.

I'm not a mac expert but it seems to me that for consistency, the systray library should call [stop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428473-stop) instead of terminate — you may want to file a bug asking for that.

Comment: thanks for the input @hobbs. as suggested, I have already filed a bug. Awaiting the action.